# New time at time zone

Tags: ruby, time

Is there a gem-free way to create a `Time` instance at a given timezone:

- using its name or abbreviation
- **without having to know if daylight savings is in effect?**

I'm using the [timezone gem](https://github.com/panthomakos/timezone) for this:

```
require 'timezone'
CDT = Time.new
# => 2016-06-22 12:23:30 -0500
tz = Timezone.fetch('America/Los_Angeles')
# => #<Timezone::Zone name: "America/Los_Angeles">
PDT = tz.time_with_offset(CDT)
# => 2016-06-22 10:23:30 -0700
```

I can get the offsets:

```
Time.zone_offset('CDT')
# => -25200
Time.zone_offset('CST')
# => -28800
```

then use these to create `Time` instances:

```
CDT=Time.new
# => 2016-06-22 12:31:17 -0500
tzoff=Time.zone_offset('PDT')
# => -25200
PDT=CDT.getlocal(tzoff)
# => 2016-06-22 10:31:17 -0700
```

This requires me to know if daylight savings is in effect and if the other timezone uses an adjustment.

Comment: If the gem does the job why are you concerned? Getting this right is extremely tricky and the Ruby core is probably not the best place to put all that cruft required to get it working properly.

Comment: I guess that I'm concerned that it's making calls to Geonames or Google to do the conversion--I should probably read the source.

Comment: Those calls are likely made on-demand if you're using lat/long lookup. You're not obligated to use those. The source will probably reveal a lot more.